# Rails Ruby gem versions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did something with the versions for Ruby of the different projects and now when I want to start a certain project I have the following Gem error:

```
/home/glory/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4:/home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /home/glory/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /home/glory/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /home/glory/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

When I type `gem env` I get:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.4 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 230) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/glory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/glory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/glory/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/glory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4
     - /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin
     - /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin
     - /home/glory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin
     - /home/glory/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /home/glory/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/glory/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/glory/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at the start of your error log:

```
/home/glory/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4:/home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global', execute `gem env` for more information
```

and in the PATH information:

```
 - /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin
 - /home/glory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin
 - /home/glory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin
 - /home/glory/.rvm/bin
 - /usr/local/heroku/bin
 - /home/glory/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
 - /home/glory/.rbenv/shims
 - /home/glory/.rbenv/bin
```

You're using rbenv and RVM.

Don't do that.

The [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation) specifically says:

> **Compatibility note:** rbenv is *incompatible* with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv.

I'd recommend removing both using

```
rm -rf ~/.rbenv
rvm implode
```

then remove their initialization lines from your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile files.

Then pick one or the other, rbenv or RVM, and reinstall only that one. This will force you to reinstall whichever Rubies you want to use along with the associated gems, but it'll also fix the mess cleanly.

Comment: Very good... This was the problem. Thank you! One of these should be removed?

Comment: Yes, one should be removed. Which one is up to you. rbenv is simple and lightweight and you can add additional features using plugins, RVM is more full-featured, bigger, and more complicated to learn as a result.

Comment: @ the Tin Man I removed RVM for the reasons you said, and because I figured out that rbenv is better for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

I think there will be problem with ruby version from where you are starting the application. 
Switch to a different ruby version in which the application created. 
You can use following versions managers to switch to a different versions

1. RVM
2. rbenv

**Usage: rvm use {ruby-version}**

Comment: May be  what ever version its showing will be Global Version. Try to switch it and run the server